# How to display text in a dynamic GridView when a button is pressed?

Tags: flutter

I want to display text in a dynamic `gridview` and when a button is pressed its value should be displayed in that `textview` inside the `gridview`.

```
child: GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 7,
            childAspectRatio: 1,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            mainAxisSpacing: 15.0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 15.0,
            children: wordList.map((String data) {
              return Card(
                color: Colors.teal,
                child: Text("",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
          )
```

[image: screenshot showing the gridview and buttons]

Comment: you need to create a list of letters having 7 blanks initially and map them to display the text in the cards. when a button is pressed, update the value in the list at that certain index using setState()

Comment: @Rahul Means the dynamic gridview will increase on the every button pressed and that pressed button text will be there in that textbox in grid? Right?

Comment: no the dynamic button gridview will not be increasing when we press it but its value is going to display in textview inside cardview i.e. in green